# Whats the difference in creating an object using the different new expression syntaxes

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, new-operator

Below are the three different ways of initialization in c++ , would you please explain whether there is any difference in these three ways if we do not have any arguments

These 3 ways work while creating an object, while returning to a function  too (ex: return new myClass)

How and where exactly do each of them fit in individually when other ways fail ?

```
myClass *p = new myClass;

myClass *p = new myClass();

myClass *p = new myClass{}
```

Comment: they all three fail if `myClass` has no default constructor

Comment: @tobi Well,there is a default constructor.And these 3 ways are working.That is the basic assumption . Thanks

Comment: It differs depending on whether you write your own constructor for `myClass`, or you are using the implicitly generated one. And then the latter case differs if `myClass` is an aggregate.  Probably this question is too broad unless you are more specific about your class's properties

Comment: I believe the first one create an instance of myClass using the default constructor, the second one create an instance of myClass using a constructor with none parameters (could be the default one), and the third one create an instance of myClass with the default constructor passing an empty array to the constructor...

Answer (score 3):

From cppreference on the [new expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new)

> For non-array type, the single object is constructed in the acquired memory area.
>
> - If initializer is absent, the object is [default-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).
> - If initializer is a parenthesized list of arguments, the object is
>     [direct-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).
> - If initializer is a brace-enclosed list of
>     arguments, the object is [list-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).
>
> If type is an array type, an array of objects is initialized.
>
> - If initializer is absent, each element is [default-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).
> - If initializer is an empty pair of parentheses, each element is [value-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).
> - If initializer is a brace-enclosed list of arguments, the array is [aggregate-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

However in your examples since there are no arguments, they are [value-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)

> Value initialization is performed when a nameless temporary object is created with the initializer consisting of an empty pair of parentheses or braces

So for your three examples

```
myClass *p = new myClass;    // default-initialized

myClass *p = new myClass();  // value-initialized

myClass *p = new myClass{};  // value-initialized
```

Comment: Worth mentioning in the answer that for the case of an empty list, `new myClass()` and `new myClass{}` are identical . (But `new myClass` may differ and it might be good to give a synopsis of how that differs).

Comment: @M.M Can you please explain how , This is what i was looking for

Comment: Super explanation ,  Before this I never knew these many definitions existed for a constructor call , it was always create an object and just do your work .

Comment: The description for `myClass{}` is subtly wrong. The type of initialization performed depends on whether `myClass` is an aggregate.